# All significant objects in the universe?

Tags: universe

Taking it to the bottom of layman's terms, what would be the shortlist of significant *things* in the universe?

A list I could think of myself would put

- **Energy** (at whatever wavelength travelling through space)
- **Gas** (Atoms and molecules floating interplanetary, interstellar and intergalactic space)
- **Rocks** (Anything from dust to planets)
- **Stars** (In more general terms, anything that is or were a star... would include also black holes, magnetars and novae)
- **Galaxies**..

Things that does not fit very well in this classifications however are:

- The super massive black hole of galaxies (although I could simply put it in galaxies)
- Dark matter (but I do not worry too much until it has been properly measured :) )
- Wormholes (if they even exist..)
- Anything else

What else is to be put in either list?

cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As can be seen in this pie chart
[image]
taken from [the Wikipeia article on "Universe"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe), the significant parts of the Universe are, in descending order, dark energy, dark matter, gas, stars, and the ghostly subatomic particles called neutrinos. That's the most laymanish terms that can be used, because nobody knows what the first two actually are.